# numpy int64 not iterable

Tags: python, numpy

Ok so I have this problem:
I have a python script that uses pytrends to show some data from Google interest over time. The function outputs not a list, but a bunch of numpy.int64 numbers. I can't do anything with them, can you guys help me out?

```py
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import datetime
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
import numpy

kw_list=['x']
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowyear = now.year
nowmonth = now.month
nowday = now.day
endday = now.day - 1

start = 0

IOT = pytrend.get_historical_interest(kw_list, year_start=nowyear, month_start=nowmonth, 
    day_start=endday, hour_start=0, 
    year_end=nowyear, month_end=nowmonth, 
    day_end=nowday, hour_end=0, 
    cat=0, geo='', gprop='', sleep=0)

firstHalf = []
secondHalf = []

while start < 24:
    start += 1
    while start < 12:
        start += 1
        firstHalf.append(IOT['x'].iloc[start])
        firstHalfSum = (firstHalf[len(firstHalf) - 1])
        print(firstHalfSum)
```

"firstHalfSum" outputs a bunch of numbers. I want their sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calculating the sum every time you loop. Remove the sum from the loop.

```
while start < 24:
    start += 1
    while start < 12:
        start += 1
        firstHalf.append(IOT['x'].iloc[start])
    print(sum(firstHalf))
```

Also a heads up that once you reach the first append `start` is already set to 2 - I assume this is undesirable.

Also the data is already in a DataFrame object why bother adding it to a list?

```
sumFirstHalf = IOT['x'].iloc[:12].sum()
```